# Cordova default config.xml URI is not registered

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to build an android app by using Cordova. However, after I created the project, added platform android, and import it into Android Studio. I met some problems with the config.xml. I didn't change anything but I still get this error.

It says URI is not registered for xmlns:cdv.

The entire xml file is this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="xxx.xxx.xxx" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <feature name="Whitelist">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <name>xxxx</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="view/index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <platform name="android">
        <icon src="res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="res/android-mdpi/icon.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="res/android-hdpi/icon.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="res/android-xhdpi/icon.png" density="xhdpi" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Solution:**

Add both files:

- `http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets`
- `http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0`

To your *Ignored Schemas and DTDs* at:

`File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Schemas and DTDs > Ignored Schemas and DTDs`.

**TL;DR:**

Android Studio is *incorrectly* assuming that these XML Namespaces are used to validate your xml (they are not), so it wants you to [register the URI](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-languages-schemas-and-dtds.html#external_schemas_and_dtds). This is unnecessary since these [XML Namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) declarations do not reference anything and do not validate anything -- they exist only as an arbitrary and unique name.

This was a tough concept for me while I was looking into this, so for clarity I'll include a direct quote from the [W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/):

> The namespace name, to serve its intended purpose, SHOULD have the
>   characteristics of uniqueness and persistence. It is not a goal that
>   it be directly usable for retrieval of a schema (if any exists).

Hence, the solution is to ignore the URI since it does not actually reference a schema.

Comment: Hi there. I have the same problem, but additionaly a third URI: http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
Is it save to add it aswell?

Comment: @Jinxi, Yes, it is probably "safe" to add any URI to your "Ignored Schemas and DTDs", but it is certainly safe to add an "android.com" URI.

Answer (score 0):

I just ignore this error. It seems that it doesn't have any bad influences. The app can still be running.